# Modifying the "sub" Claim in Firebase Token using C# Backend

Tags: c#, firebase, asp.net-web-api, jwt

I am working on a backend application using C# and Firebase Authentication. I have a specific requirement where I need to modify the "sub" claim in the Firebase token, which represents the unique identifier (UID) of the authenticated user.

Please note that I understand the security implications and considerations related to modifying the "sub" claim, and I am looking for guidance in scenarios where such customization is necessary within the bounds of best practices.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to [mint a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens), which (is the only way that) allows you to specify the UID of a user - as well as all other claims.

Comment: Is it possible to set a custom value for the sub claim on the backend, considering that the provided API only allows adding additional claims?

Comment: Not through the Firebase API. As you can see the UID is passed separate from the other claims, as Firebase Authentication gives special meaning to that. There might be other libraries that allow you to manipulate the JWT of course, but you'd definitely have to test how that then works with Firebase Auth. --- Overall this sounds very much like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) though, so you might want to edit your question to clarify the end goal that you're trying to meet by modifying a single claim in a JWT somebody else minted.